# How to count number of records per day?

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I have a table in a with the following structure:

```
CustID --- DateAdded ---

 396       2012-02-09 
 396       2012-02-09 
 396       2012-02-08 
 396       2012-02-07 
 396       2012-02-07
 396       2012-02-07 
 396       2012-02-06
 396       2012-02-06
```

I would like to know how I can count the number of records per day, for the last 7 days in SQL and then return this as an integer.

At present I have the following SQL query written:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Responses
 WHERE DateAdded >= dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, GetDate()) - 7, 0)

RETURN
```

However this only returns all entries for the past 7 days. How can I count the records per day for the last 7 days?

Comment: GROUP BY DateAdded. Is that MSSQL?

Comment: @BrunoCosta Yes MSSQL on SQLServer

Comment: GetDate()) - 7 will return last 8 days records(including current day)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
select DateAdded, count(CustID)
from Responses
WHERE DateAdded >=dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,GetDate())- 7,0)
GROUP BY DateAdded
```

Answer (score 11):

```
select DateAdded, count(CustID)
from tbl
group by DateAdded
```

about 7-days interval it's DB-depending question

Comment: @Rupert This is the one you should be using. If you're using a scripting language to auto-execute the query, you can use SQL's `TO_CHAR` function to create comparable dates (which is especially relevant when it comes to timestamp fields).

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT DateAdded, COUNT(1) AS NUMBERADDBYDAY
FROM Responses
WHERE DateAdded >= dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,GetDate())- 7,0)
GROUP BY DateAdded
```

Answer (score 3):

This one is like the answer above which uses the MySql DATE_FORMAT() function. I also selected just one specific week in Jan.

```
SELECT 
    DatePart(day, DateAdded) AS date, 
    COUNT(entryhash) AS count 
FROM Responses 
    where DateAdded > '2020-01-25' and DateAdded < '2020-02-01' 
GROUP BY 
    DatePart(day, DateAdded )
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (DATE(dateadded)) AS unique_date, COUNT(*) AS amount
FROM table
GROUP BY unique_date
ORDER BY unique_date ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

If your timestamp includes time, not only date, use:

`SELECT DATE_FORMAT('timestamp', '%Y-%m-%d') AS date, COUNT(id) AS count FROM table GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT('timestamp', '%Y-%m-%d')`

Comment: Worth noting that "DATE_FORMAT" is a MySql function and does not work with SQL Server

Comment: `FORMAT(DateAdded, 'yyyy-MM-dd')` works in SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(*), dateadded FROM Responses
WHERE DateAdded >=dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,GetDate())- 7,0)
group by dateadded

RETURN
```

This will give you a count of records for each dateadded value.  Don't make the mistake of adding more columns to the select, expecting to get just one count per day.  The group by clause will give you a row for every unique instance of the columns listed.

Answer (score 0):

```
select DateAdded, count(DateAdded) as num_records
from your_table
WHERE DateAdded >=dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,GetDate())- 7,0)
group by DateAdded
order by DateAdded
```

Comment: Works fine... But when one day among last 7 days, has no record means, it didn't show that day with count as zero. How can we list out that record?

Comment: You can ask your own question about it with the query you tried, example data and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the best answer here IMO is a comment by @Profex on an incorrect answer , but the solution I went with is

```
SELECT FORMAT(DateAdded, 'yyyy-MM-dd'), count(CustID)
FROM Responses
WHERE DateAdded >= dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,GetDate())- 7,0)
GROUP BY FORMAT(DateAdded, 'yyyy-MM-dd')
ORDER BY FORMAT(DateAdded, 'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

Note that I haven't tested this SQL since I don't have the OP's DB , but this approach works well in my scenario where the date is stored to the second

The important part here is using the `FORMAT(DateAdded, 'yyyy-MM-dd')` method to drop the time without losing the year and month , as would happen if you used `DATEPART(day, DateAdded)`

Answer (score 0):

When a day among last 7 days, has no record means, the following code will list out that day with count as zero.

```
DECLARE @startDate DATE = GETDATE() - 6,
        @endDate DATE = GETDATE();

DECLARE @daysTable TABLE
(
OrderDate date
)

DECLARE @daysOrderTable TABLE
(
OrderDate date,
OrderCount int
)

Insert into @daysTable
SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @startDate, @endDate) + 1)
        Date = DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.object_id) - 1, @startDate)
FROM    sys.all_objects a
        CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects b;


Insert into @daysOrderTable
select OrderDate, ISNULL((SELECT COUNT(*) AS OdrCount
                            FROM [dbo].[MyOrderTable] odr
                            WHERE CAST(odr.[CreatedDate] as date) = dt.OrderDate
                            group by CAST(odr.[CreatedDate] as date)
                        ), 0) AS OrderCount from @daysTable dt

select * from @daysOrderTable
```

## RESULT

```
OrderDate     OrderCount
2022-11-22     42
2022-11-23     6
2022-11-24     34
2022-11-25     0
2022-11-26     28
2022-11-27     0
2022-11-28     22
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DateAdded, '%Y-%m-%d'), 
       COUNT(CustID) 
FROM Responses 
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(DateAdded, '%Y-%m-%d');
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post