# Oracle Count number of records each hour

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I'm trying to get the number of records created each hour but running into trouble with getting the results to group correctly. The idea is similiar to: [How to count number of records per day?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229862/how-to-count-number-of-records-per-day)

However, the field I'm using to Group by is a Date-time field that records down to the second. This seems to be causing trouble with the Group By statement, as when the query returns, there is one row for each second in the specified time period, which is way too much data and will make the work I want to do with the results more difficult than it needs to be (if for no other reason that it's too many rows to fit on one Excel sheet).

My current code is:

```
SELECT ASD, Count(ASD) Num_CR
From DB_Name.Table_Name fcr
Where trunc(fcr.ASD) > to_Char('31-DEC-2014')
    And trunc(fcr.ASD) < to_Char('31-JAN-2015')
    And fcr.Status_Code = 'C'
Group By ASD
Order By ASD;
```

I've tried changing the Group By to be trunc(ASD), but that results in Toad throwing this error: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you add `trunc()` to grouping.. you have to do the same in `select` and `order by` as well.. To go by logic, you can select and order only, what you grouped..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use aggregation anything in the `select` and `order by` clauses must match what's in the `group by clause`:

```
SELECT trunc(ASD,'hh'), Count(ASD) Num_CR
From DB_Name.Table_Name fcr
Where trunc(fcr.ASD) > to_date('31-DEC-2014')
    And trunc(fcr.ASD) < to_date('31-JAN-2015')
    And fcr.Status_Code = 'C'
Group By trunc(ASD,'hh')
Order By trunc(ASD,'hh');
```

---

When applied to a date, `trunc` will truncate to the day. To truncate to a different level, specify the format of the element you'd like to truncate to as the second argument (e.g. `'hh'` will truncate to the hour; `'mm'` will truncate to the month).

Comment: Worked like a charm. Hadn't been specifying the 'hh' in the trunc statements, guess that was the issue.

Comment: Rocks like a bullet.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT to_char(ASD,'DD-MM-YYYY HH'), Count(ASD) Num_CR
From DB_Name.Table_Name fcr
Where trunc(fcr.ASD) > to_Char('31-DEC-2014')
    And trunc(fcr.ASD) < to_Char('31-JAN-2015')
    And fcr.Status_Code = 'C'
Group By to_char(ASD,'DD-MM-YYYY HH')
Order By to_char(ASD,'DD-MM-YYYY HH');
```

Quick and dirty :)

Comment: This solution will sort by day first, so February 1 will come between January 1 and January 2. It's generally best to leave dates in the `date` data type until the formatting is actually necessary (i.e. for display).

Answer (score 1):

First off, why are you doing `to_char` on something that's already a string? Secondly, why are you trying to compare something that's (presumably) a DATE column to a string? That way lies madness...

I think you're after something like:

```
SELECT   trunc(ASD, 'hh') asd_hr, Count(ASD) Num_CR
From     DB_Name.Table_Name fcr
Where    trunc(fcr.ASD) > to_date('31/12/2014', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
And      trunc(fcr.ASD) < to_date('31/01/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
And      fcr.Status_Code = 'C'
Group By trunc(ASD, 'hh')
Order By trunc(ASD, 'hh');
```

Also worth noting, did you mean to exclude the last day of January from your query? If so, then fine, but if not, then perhaps you should change it to `to_date('01/02/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy')`