# PDO fetchAll to array different output than SQL request

Tags: php, sql, pdo

i have MySQL DB, which stores data every minute (for date 1.7.2017 i have 1012 values of 1):

```
id| value |timeDate
1 | 1     |2017-07-01 ...
2 | 0     |2017-07-01 ...
3 | 1     |2017-07-01 ...
.....
```

I want to daily count values with value 1 (function):

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT day(dTimeDate), COUNT(*) FROM sensorData
        WHERE MONTH(dTimeDate) = :dateMonth AND YEAR(dTimeDate) = :dateYear AND _idSensor = :idSensor AND dValue = :valueSensor
        GROUP BY dTimeDate");
$stmt->execute(array(':dateMonth' => $m, ':dateYear' => $y, ':idSensor' => $idSensor, ':valueSensor' => $valueSensor));
$row2 =$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach ($row2 as $row) {
    echo $row['day(dTimeDate)']. ' - ' .$row['COUNT(*)'].'<br/>';
}
```

I expect to get (like my SQL, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229862/how-to-count-number-of-records-per-day)):

```
(day | Count)
1 - 1012 (count all values with value 1 in day 1)
2 - 105
...(31 lines, one for every day)
```

Instead i get:

```
(day | Count)
1 - 1
1 - 1
...(1012 lines of day 1 and value 1)
2 - 1
```

`row2` returns array of all data instead of daily.

How can i get expected values?

Comment: Try to `GROUP BY dTimeDate, value`

Comment: I tried, get the same data.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your codes behaviour. I am not sure what you mean by your expected results. What are 1 and 2? The id or the value?

Comment: My select 'SELECT day(dTimeDate), COUNT(*) FROM sensorData' returns day and count values. That means 'day 1 - 1012(count values by day 1). 'row2' reurns array of all data (see update).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a little mistake in code:-

Change `group by dTimeDate` to `group by day(dTimeDate)`

Corrected complete code

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT day(dTimeDate), COUNT(*) FROM sensorData
    WHERE MONTH(dTimeDate) = :dateMonth AND YEAR(dTimeDate) = :dateYear AND _idSensor = :idSensor AND dValue = :valueSensor
    GROUP BY day(dTimeDate)");

$stmt->execute(array(':dateMonth' => $m, ':dateYear' => $y, ':idSensor' => $idSensor, ':valueSensor' => $valueSensor));
$row2 =$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach ($row2 as $row) {
    echo $row['day(dTimeDate)']. ' - ' .$row['COUNT(*)'].'<br/>';
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this obvious mistake, which take me allmost 2 days :)

Comment: It's OK, n Welcome. Just a Suggestion. When you are not able to find bugs, either do debugging line by line or leave the thing for few hours and then just review it.