# Cumulative count on date data from datetime format

Tags: sql, date, group-by, count, window-functions

I have a table looks like:

```
ID entry_time
abc123 2020-05-29 10:29:18.000
def456 2020-05-30 13:12:43.000
...
```

I want to do cumulative count by date, so I did:

`select entry_time, count (*) OVER (ORDER BY entry_time) as TOTAL_NUM from my_table;`

It is okay, but it will count based on `datetime` format. I would like to count only on `date` (i.e. by day, don't care about time).

How would I do that?

Many thanks,

Comment: which sql engine are you using?

Comment: In your resultset, do you want one row by `datetime` (as in your original table), or one row by `date`?

Comment: have you seen this [similar Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229862/how-to-count-number-of-records-per-day)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want one record per day, you can use aggregation and window functions:

```
select
    date(entry_time) entry_day,
    sum(count(*)) over(order by date(entry_time)) total_num
from mytable
group by date(entry_time)
order by entry_day
```

This assumes that your database supports the `date()`, that converts a `datetime` to a `date` (as in MySQL for example). If it does not, it sure has an alternative way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

You can try by converting `entry time` to date.

```
select 
    convert(date, entry_time) as entry_time, 
    count (*) OVER (ORDER BY convert(date, entry_time)) as total_num 
from my_table;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use convert or cast entry_time to Date

```
select entry_time, count (*) OVER (ORDER BY Convert(date,entry_time)) as TOTAL_NUM from my_table;

OR

select entry_time, count (*) OVER (ORDER BY Cast(entry_timeas as date)) as TOTAL_NUM from my_table;
```